# Is it legal to bring Li-Ion batteries in a homemade electronic on a plane from Canada to Costa Rica

Tags: air-travel, aircraft

I am going on a school trip to Costa Rica for a bit over a week and I was going to make and bring a Solar Powered phone/USB charger for my phone and camera.

The Solar Powered charger will have 2 internal Li-Ion batteries which are 3.7VDC and 2800 mAh each. For a total of 7.4VDC and 2800 mAh in total.

Are there any restrictions or laws that would prevent me from bringing homemade electronics or these Li-Ion batteries on a plane from Canada to Costa Rica?

Comment: Your total is wrong. The batteries are either connected serially, giving you 7.4V and 2800mAh, or in parallel giving you 3.7V and 5600mAh.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the CATSA guidance here: [Guidelines for Batteries](http://www.catsa.gc.ca/guidelines-batteries)

And the FAA (connection?) guidance here: [Batteries Carried by Airline Passengers](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ash/ash_programs/hazmat/passenger_info/media/Airline_passengers_and_batteries.pdf)

Unless I'm really bad at math today, you are under the limit.

There are no specific restrictions on homemade electronics though you must still pass the screening process at the terminal entrance and Customs in Costa Rica.

Comment: Canada to Costa Rica does not usually involve a US connection, although one can book it using US airlines.  WestJet and Air Canada both fly to San Jose, CR.